# Decompose large bipartite graph into small bipartite graphs?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs

Given a bipartite graph $G$ with parts $A_i$ and $B_i$ with maximum degree $d$.
We may assume that $|U|,|V|\le n$ and $n\ge d$.

I am wondering is it possible to decompose $G$ into vertex-disjoint bipartite graphs $G_i$ with parts $A_i, B_i$ such that $|A_i|, |B_i|=d^{O(1)}$, assuming that $d$ is fixed and $n$ tends to infinity, and $$\left|E(G)\setminus\bigcup_i E(G_i)\right| = d^{O(1)}?$$

Comment: Probably not? you want to decompose it into n/ d^O(1) many parts. But if the original graph is connected, then each part would have an edge leaving it. So the number of edges between parts would be at least on the order of the number of parts...i.e. more like n / d^O(1), not d^O(1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $G$ is allowed to be an arbitrary bipartite graph with maximum degree $d$, and $d$ is allowed to be an arbitrary fixed integer, the answer is NO. In fact, if $G$ is **any connected** bipartite graph on $n$ vertices and with maximum degree $d$ and each $G_i$ has $d^{O(1)}$ vertices, the condition $$\left|E(G)\setminus\bigcup_i E(G_i)\right| = d^{O(1)}$$  is **never** met, provided $n$ is large enough relative to $d$ more precisely $n > (d^{O(1)})^2+1$.

Indeed, let $G$ be a connected bipartite graph on $n$ vertices and with maximum degree $d$, and assume $n$ is large enough relative to $d$. Then contract each $G_i$ to a single vertex $v_i$ and call the resulting graph $G'$. Then, as $G$ is connected then so must $G'$ be connected. So we now show that the bound on the number of edges between the $G_i$s forces $G'$ to be not connected however. To this end, $G'$ has $n/d^{O(1)} >> d^{O(1)}$ vertices, as each $G_i$ has only $d^{O(1)}$ vertices. However, the number of edges in $G'$ is only $\left|E(G)\setminus\bigcup_i E(G_i)\right|$ $=$ $d^{O(1)}$. Thus, $G'$ has many more vertices [$n/d^{O(1)}$ vertices] than edges [only $d^{O(1)}$ edges] so it is impossible for $G'$ to be connected after all. Thus, as $G'$ is not connected, the graph $G$ cannot be connected either, which contradicts the given that $G$ is connected.